# Masstransit Azure Service Bus 404 errors in log

Tags: masstransit

I'm using Masstransit with Azure Service Bus to process a saga using dotnet core. The core functionality of the application works as expected but the logs for Masstransit shows 404 errors when trying to access an internal queue that it creates.

The exceptions logged are:

```
Exception received on receiver: sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg?autodelete=300 during AcceptMessageSession
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: 
The messaging entity 'sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg' could not be found. 
TrackingId:1e0d96d2-b15f-413a-8453-cd924ad2595b_G31, SystemTracker:MYSB.servicebus.windows.net:MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg, Timestamp:2019-02-25T20:47:57.

ReceiveTransport Faulted: sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg?autodelete=300
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg' could not be found. TrackingId:1e0d96d2-b15f-413a-8453-cd924ad2595b_G31, SystemTracker:MYSB.servicebus.windows.net:MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg, Timestamp:2019-02-25T20:47:57.)) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg' could not be found. TrackingId:1e0d96d2-b15f-413a-8453-cd924ad2595b_G31, SystemTracker:MYSB.servicebus.windows.net:MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg, Timestamp:2019-02-25T20:47:57.) ---> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg' could not be found. TrackingId:1e0d96d2-b15f-413a-8453-cd924ad2595b_G31, SystemTracker:MYSB.servicebus.windows.net:MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg, Timestamp:2019-02-25T20:47:57.
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(String sessionId, TimeSpan operationTimeout) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\SessionClient.cs:line 334
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionReceivePump.SessionPumpTaskAsync() in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\SessionReceivePump.cs:line 125
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.MessageReceiverFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.ClientContext>.Send(ClientContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.MessageReceiverFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.ClientContext>.Send(ClientContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.ReceiveTransport.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<Receiver>b__0>d.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg' could not be found. TrackingId:1e0d96d2-b15f-413a-8453-cd924ad2595b_G31, SystemTracker:MYSB.servicebus.windows.net:MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg, Timestamp:2019-02-25T20:47:57.) ---> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg' could not be found. TrackingId:1e0d96d2-b15f-413a-8453-cd924ad2595b_G31, SystemTracker:MYSB.servicebus.windows.net:MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg, Timestamp:2019-02-25T20:47:57.
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(String sessionId, TimeSpan operationTimeout) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\SessionClient.cs:line 334
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionReceivePump.SessionPumpTaskAsync() in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\SessionReceivePump.cs:line 125
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://MYSB.servicebus.windows.net/MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg' could not be found. TrackingId:1e0d96d2-b15f-413a-8453-cd924ad2595b_G31, SystemTracker:MYSB.servicebus.windows.net:MYCOMPNAME_dotnet_bus-_dkdyyybrsrcgyw19bdmjsapuyg, Timestamp:2019-02-25T20:47:57.
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(String sessionId, TimeSpan operationTimeout) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\SessionClient.cs:line 334
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SessionReceivePump.SessionPumpTaskAsync() in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\SessionReceivePump.cs:line 125<---
<---
```

The errors start about 5 mins after the application has started, which seems to be when that queue is set to autodelete. Note that the queue causing the error is not the one I'm using for the saga in the application, it seems to be queue created by an internal process in Masstransit.

Any help with what is causing this or information on what this queue is used for would be appreciated.

(Edit)
Configuration:

```
    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
    {
        // SetEntityNameFormatters

        var host = cfg.Host(
            new Uri(settings.HostAddress),
            h =>
            {
                h.TransportType = TransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
                h.RetryLimit = settings.RetryLimit;
                h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(settings.TimeOutSeconds);
                h.TokenProvider =
                    TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(settings.KeyName,
                        settings.SharedAccessKey);
            });

        cfg.ConfigureDefaultSettings(queueSettings.Default);

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, $"{environment}.{queueSettings.Queue.Name}", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureReceiverSettings(queueSettings.Queue);

            e.Saga<SagaConsumer>(serviceProvider);
            e.Consumer<SagaFaultConsumer>(serviceProvider);
            e.RemoveSubscriptions = true;
        });

        cfg.UseSerilog(Log.Logger);
        cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
    });

    bus.Start();
```

The ConfigureDefaultSettings and ConfigureReceiverSettings methods setup the bus based on appsettings. The setting I currently have are:

```
  "AzureConnectionSettings": {
    "RetryLimit": 5,
    "TimeOutSeconds": 5
  },
  "QueueSettings": {
    "Default": {
      "RequireSession": true,
      "DuplicateDetection": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "HistoryTimeWindowMinutes": 5
      },
      "RetryPolicy": {
        "Type": "Exponential",
        "RetryLimit": 5,
        "MinIntervalSeconds": 1,
        "MaxIntervalSeconds": 10,
        "DeltaSeconds": 5
      }
    },
    "Queue": {
      "Name": "QueueName",
      "RequireSession": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Set require session to false for default

Comment: Thanks Chris, that worked once the queues were recreated. Do you mind just explaining what that additional queue is used for, and why that setting change worked? Also if you can add it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @thilinab did you ever manage to find out why this is working? And the additional queue?